# How to not consider Row delimiter which is present in the column data in Informatica Source

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I am having a csv file as source with ; as Column Delimiter,LF as Row Delimiter and my data is enclosed within "". If i get LF(Row delimiter) in data we should not consider it as Row Delimiter.My target is Oracle database.
How to get the required output below while using informatica.

Input:

```
"Ram";"Hyderabad"LF
"Sita";"Hyderabad,LF
INDIA-500084."LF
```

Required Output should be 2 rows only:

```
Name             Address
Ram              Hyderabad
Sita             Hyderabad, INDIA-500084.
```

Wrong Output i am getting is 3 rows:

```
Name              Address
Ram               Hyderabad
Sita              Hyderabad,
INDIA-500084.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you need to do a find & replace on your source before processing to get rid of those `LF` strings within double quotes.

Unfortunatelly, Informatica probably does a split on `LF` to rows first, so you need to reprocess the source before Informatica reads it. Try using `Command` as `Source` and use `sed`.

Comment: Thanks Maciejg but can i replace LF with any other charcater? If yes can you please provide the command.

Comment: What you're looking to do is read through the file and remove all line feeds that are within inverted commas before processing the file further. More fruitful would be to stop those line feeds from getting generated in the inverted commas by the process which creates your input file (perl more than sed regular expressions will be able to remove it but it'll be a faff on to make sure it only picks up and removes the line feeds from within inverted commas but leaves the rest alone)

Answer (score 0):

In the 'Config Object' tab of the session put the override for 'Custom Properties' as MatchQuotesPastEndOfLine=Yes;

This will read the lines even after the LF till it sees the end of quotes.